# Nested dictionary in a loop

Tags: python, csv, dictionary

I have a CSV file that looks something like this: [image] It shows electricity consumption of 4 countries from 1980 to 2014. I'm trying to create a nested dictionary where for example `consumption['United States'][1980]` will return the correct value. I have an array with the list of integer years and I'm trying to create the dictionary like this:

```
 file = open('power dataset.csv', 'r')

years = list(range(1980, 2015))

consumption = {}
generation = {}

generation = False

for line in file:

    if("Nuclear" in line):
        break

    split = line.split(",")

    if split[0] == "Generation":
        generation = True

    if  "Egypt" == split[0] or split[0] == "Germany" or split[0] == "Netherlands" or split[0] == "United States":

        values = split[2:]

        if not generation:

            i = 0

            for year in years:
                country = split[0]
                consumption[country] = {year: values[i]}
                i = i+1
```

where values is an array containing the values of the corresponding year. The problem I'm having is that the dictionary ends up only containing one year and one value (which are the last ones). So if I try printing something like `consumption['United States'][1980]` I get an error because there's no entry for 1980 in the dictionary, only 2014.

I feel like I'm missing something fairly simple but I can't quite put my finger on it.

[Here](http://pastebin.com/zHgS4UEZ) is the entire CSV file.

Comment: Without seeing how you declare `split`, `country` and `consumption` we can not help

Comment: Posted more code.

Comment: is there a particular reason you are not using Pandas? that would be much more appropriate

Comment: @tobias_k Oh my bad, I tried changing that line for testing. This is the one without errors.

Comment: @Swailem95 And does that version still have the problem with showing only one dict?

Comment: @tobias_k Yes it does.

Comment: Can you post a short excerpt of your csv data for testing?

Comment: Posted all of it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem seems to be that with this:

```
for year in years:
    consumption[country] = {year: values[i]}
```

you overwrite the previous value for `consumption[country]` in each iteration of the loop.

Instead, try this:

```
if country in ("Egypt", "Germany", "Netherlands", "United States"):
    if not generation:
        consumption[country] = {year: vals for year, vals in zip(years, values)}
```

Step-by-step breakdown example of the dictionary-comprehension with [`zip`](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/functions.html#zip):

```
>>> years = [1980, 1981, 1982, 1983]
>>> values = [1, 2, 3, 4]
>>> zip(years, values)
[(1980, 1), (1981, 2), (1982, 3), (1983, 4)]
>>> {year: vals for year, vals in zip(years, values)}
{1980: 1, 1981: 2, 1982: 3, 1983: 4}
```

Alternatively, you could initialize `consumption[country]` as `consumption[country] = {}` before the inner loop and then use `consumption[country][year] = values[i]` as in your original code before the edit.

Comment: Would you mind explaining what this is doing? Also, how can it be overwritten if the year is always different?

Comment: Ah cool, didn't know about that zip function - and yes the reset is intentional. Although I know your solution works, I'm still trying to figure out why the values are overwritten even though the years are unique, it should work but it doesn't.

Comment: @Swailem95 Yes, the years are unique, but you _overwrite_ the entire `consumption[country]`  dict.

Comment: @Swailem95 When you write `consumption[country] = {year: values[i]}` it completely replaces the dictionary entry `consumption[country]`. You mean to add the new value as `consumption[country][year] = values[i]'. It is the difference between `a = [val]` and `a.append(val)`